# FFMPEG split video to segments with audio

Tags: ffmpeg, playlist

I'm tying to split mov file to .ts segments with m3u8 playlist.
All is ok except of audio. Audio doesn't work and it seems that ffmpeg ignores audio stream.

This is my command:

```
ffmpeg -i stepteen2.mov 
       -c:a aac 
       -c:v libx264 
       -an 
       -map 0 
       -muxdelay 0 
       -muxpreload 0 
       -output_ts_offset 0 
       -segment_time 2 
       -segment_wrap 1000 
       -segment_list_size 0 
       -segment_list temp.m3u8 
       -segment_list_flags +cache 
       -segment_list_type m3u8 
       -f segment 
       temp-%03d.ts
```

After this command I receive 5 ts segments and m3u8 playlist with segment paths list.
If I open properties of segment files there are no any information in Audio and Video tabs (although video works)

This is output:

```
ffmpeg version n4.1.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1)
  configuration: --prefix= --prefix=/usr --disable-debug --disable-doc --disable-static --enable-avisynth --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-libdrm --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-sdl2 --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxcb --enable-libxvid --enable-nonfree --enable-nvenc --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-shared --enable-vaapi --enable-vdpau --enable-version3 --enable-xlib
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'stepteen2.mov':
  Metadata:
    creation_time   : 1998-11-12T18:28:20.000000Z
  Duration: 00:00:28.60, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 111 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: svq1 (SVQ1 / 0x31515653), yuv410p, 160x120, 90 kb/s, 7.52 fps, 7.50 tbr, 600 tbn, 600 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1998-11-12T18:28:20.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Video Media Handler
      encoder         : Sorenson Video
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: qdmc (QDMC / 0x434D4451), 44100 Hz, mono, s16, 20 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1998-11-12T18:28:20.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Sound Media Handler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (svq1 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0x55a5a80b8dc0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0x55a5a80b8dc0] profile High, level 1.0
[libx264 @ 0x55a5a80b8dc0] 264 - core 152 r2854 e9a5903 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2017 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=4 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=7 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
[segment @ 0x55a5a7fd2e00] Opening 'temp-000.ts' for writing
Output #0, segment, to 'temp-%03d.ts':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (libx264), yuv420p, 160x120, q=-1--1, 7.50 fps, 90k tbn, 7.50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1998-11-12T18:28:20.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Video Media Handler
      encoder         : Lavc58.35.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
[segment @ 0x55a5a7fd2e00] Opening 'temp.m3u8.tmp' for writing
[segment @ 0x55a5a7fd2e00] Opening 'temp-001.ts' for writing
[segment @ 0x55a5a7fd2e00] Opening 'temp.m3u8.tmp' for writing
[segment @ 0x55a5a7fd2e00] Opening 'temp-002.ts' for writing
[segment @ 0x55a5a7fd2e00] Opening 'temp.m3u8.tmp' for writing
[segment @ 0x55a5a7fd2e00] Opening 'temp-003.ts' for writing
[segment @ 0x55a5a7fd2e00] Opening 'temp.m3u8.tmp' for writing
[segment @ 0x55a5a7fd2e00] Opening 'temp-004.ts' for writing
[segment @ 0x55a5a7fd2e00] Opening 'temp.m3u8.tmp' for writing
[segment @ 0x55a5a7fd2e00] Opening 'temp-005.ts' for writing
[segment @ 0x55a5a7fd2e00] Opening 'temp.m3u8.tmp' for writing
frame=  215 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:28.26 bitrate=N/A speed= 162x    
video:217kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
[libx264 @ 0x55a5a80b8dc0] frame I:8     Avg QP:14.15  size:  2625
[libx264 @ 0x55a5a80b8dc0] frame P:93    Avg QP:21.28  size:  1295
[libx264 @ 0x55a5a80b8dc0] frame B:114   Avg QP:24.62  size:   703
[libx264 @ 0x55a5a80b8dc0] consecutive B-frames: 27.0%  2.8% 12.6% 57.7%
[libx264 @ 0x55a5a80b8dc0] mb I  I16..4: 28.3% 23.0% 48.8%
[libx264 @ 0x55a5a80b8dc0] mb P  I16..4:  1.5%  6.2%  7.0%  P16..4: 21.3% 17.8% 15.1%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:31.1%
[libx264 @ 0x55a5a80b8dc0] mb B  I16..4:  1.2%  1.8%  1.5%  B16..8: 28.1% 16.0% 10.0%  direct:11.0%  skip:30.4%  L0:43.4% L1:31.9% BI:24.8%
[libx264 @ 0x55a5a80b8dc0] 8x8 transform intra:35.9% inter:39.5%
[libx264 @ 0x55a5a80b8dc0] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 73.6% 71.0% 48.2% inter: 34.9% 32.7% 4.3%
[libx264 @ 0x55a5a80b8dc0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 61% 12% 26%  2%
[libx264 @ 0x55a5a80b8dc0] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 32% 14% 23%  5%  4%  5%  4%  7%  6%
[libx264 @ 0x55a5a80b8dc0] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 31% 16% 15%  6%  5%  8%  6%  7%  7%
[libx264 @ 0x55a5a80b8dc0] i8c dc,h,v,p: 53% 17% 21%  9%
[libx264 @ 0x55a5a80b8dc0] Weighted P-Frames: Y:14.0% UV:9.7%
[libx264 @ 0x55a5a80b8dc0] ref P L0: 65.2% 16.8% 12.2%  5.4%  0.4%
[libx264 @ 0x55a5a80b8dc0] ref B L0: 92.3%  6.2%  1.4%
[libx264 @ 0x55a5a80b8dc0] ref B L1: 97.3%  2.7%
[libx264 @ 0x55a5a80b8dc0] kb/s:61.84
```

I see that Output #0, segment, to 'temp-%03d.ts' contains only video stream:

```
Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (libx264), yuv420p, 160x120, q=-1--1, 7.50 fps, 90k tbn, 7.50 tbc (default)
...
video:217kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `-an`. This option means "no audio".